# Get error when import any dependency with React Native

Tags: react-native

After init a React Native project, if i install and import any other dependency, it will show this error message after run "react-native run-ios":

[image: Error Message with react-native run-ios]

For e.g: I run "react-native init RNProject" to create simple react native project. After that i install react-navigation by :"npm install --save-dev react-navigation" then i import createStackNavigator by "import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';" in App.js and do nothing. After run "react-native run-ios" and got that error above. Remove the "import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';" will cause the app run normally.

I tried "rm node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/fixtures/files/package.json" or "rm ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/**fixtures**/files/package.json" but the terminal show "No such file or directory".

#### My Environment

```
| software         | version
| ---------------- | -------
| react-navigation | 2.6.2
| react-native     | 0.56.0
| node             | 8.11.3
| npm              | 5.3.0
| MacOS            | 10.13.5
```

Comment: try deleting node modules directory and package.json file. Then run `npm install` and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

Because you used `--save-dev` in install cmd which means it will be installed as `devDependencies` in your project.

**Solution:** 
Try just installing with this `npm install --save  react-navigation` which will install it as `dependencies`;

Look at you **package.json** if you find `react-navigation` this in `dependencies` section and still find same problem try deleting `node_modules` and `npm i`

Answer (score 1):

seem it could not install react-navigation.maybe you have problem with network .
try again `npm install --save  react-navigation` and look inside of `react-native` folder for   `react-navigation` folder.if it dont exist therefore it didnt install.you should find out what is problem with install.
in additional you should run `react-native link` after installing any library.

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem.

Change version `react-native`   => `0.55.0`

And then => `npm install`